# Update Excel data to HDFS on real time basis

Tags: excel, hadoop, apache-kafka, hdfs, streaming

I am having an excel in my local machine and HDFS on a remote RHEL server.
I want to load this excel data into HDFS and update it on real time basis.
For example, if some new records are inserted in excel, those needs to captured and updated in HDFS real time.
I have 2 methods in my mind now:

1) To Pull the excel file periodically and load it into HDFS and then create a hive table on top of it.
But this method unnecessarily runs the job multiple times a day and is not really a real time scenario.

2) Another Solution is to code a producer that reads the excel line by line in a loop and if some changes is captured, push the data to Kafka Topic and later can be consumed using Spark-Streaming.

But both these options are not quite straight forward, the 2nd option requires lot of coding.

Is there any better way to achieve this. I am new to streaming and couldn't quite figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on how much data you're dealing with. The fact you're discussing a single Excel file suggests this isn't a big data problem, and so Spark Streaming/Kafka would be overkill.

I'd write a vanilla Java app (using the Apache POI and Hadoop HDFS APIs) that runs constantly, checking for a change in the Excel file's last modified date (`file.lastModified()`), then reads the file and pushes its entire contents to HDFS. HDFS isn't really designed for appending, so you should re-create the entire file each time.